# Angular - Custom filter not working inside directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have simple filter which just replace some string with another (more user friendly one)

it looks like:

```
historyApp.filter('zeroKiller', function () {
    return function (text) {
        if (text==="0" || text==="" || text==="0000-00-00") text = "Unknown"
        return text;
    };
});
```

This filter works correctly in my index.html file, however i inject some aditional HTML file as directive

This is how directive looks like:

```
historyApp.directive('caseDetail', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: '../templates/caseDetail.html'
    };
});
```

this is how it is in HTML

```
   <tr ng-if="toggle" ng-repeat-end case-detail></tr>
```

And last but not least is my directive HTML page:

```
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2">
        Creation date of case<br />
        <strong>{{case.date_created | limitTo:dateLimit}}</strong><br />
        Total loss <br />
        <strong>{{case.totalloss | zeroKiller}}</strong><br />
        VIN <br />
        <strong>{{case.vin}}</strong><br />
        Vehicle <br />
        <strong>{{case.manufacturer}} {{case.model}} {{case.submodel}}</strong><br />
        AudaIN used<br />
        <strong>{{case.audavin_triggered | zeroKiller}}</strong><br />
        Accident date <br />
        <strong>{{case.accident_date | limitTo:dateLimit | zeroKiller}}</strong><br />
        Vehicle registration date <br />
        <strong>{{case.registration_date | limitTo:dateLimit | zeroKiller}}</strong><br />
        Manufactoring year <br />
        <strong>{{case.manufacturing_year | zeroKiller}}</strong>
    </td>
```

As you can see I have the filter here multiple times, but it's not running.
It basicly just display 0000-00-00 or empty string
First I think that problem is in if / else statement however I try to console log always when angular go use this filter

```
historyApp.filter('zeroKiller', function () {
    return function (text) {
        if (text==="0" || text==="" || text==="0000-00-00" || text===null || text===false) {
            var previousText = text;
            text ="Unknown";
            console.log("went in for "+previousText);
        }
        return text;
    };
});
```

And it goes in just for filter results from main page. I think it looks like FILTERS NOT WORKING IN DIRECTIVES.
I really expect this is going to be something super stupid but I can't figurate out where is a problem.

Can someone with more experience with angular throw some advise?
Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by not running? what do you get?

Comment: I get nothing, no error, also string doesn't change  it display normaly so for example as empty (nothing) or 0000-00-00

Comment: If you console `text` are you able to see what is being passed?

Comment: Can you create a Plunker that reproduces the problem?

Comment: it say : went in for 0
What is from index.html where I pass same thing same way: 
<th not-zero data-label="Owner: ">{{case.orgName | zeroKiller}}</th>

Comment: I just tried it in a plnkr, everything works fine http://plnkr.co/edit/OA7N1rvJUKIrkxno4WiO weird

Comment: BTW, your condition doesn't cover the case where text is `0` rather than `"0"`. You can change the condition in the filter to `if (!text || text === "0" || text === "0000-00-00")`

Comment: Another question: what is `dateLimit`, and what are possible values of `accident_date` and `registration_date`?

Comment: Okey guys, I just find out what was a problem. My caseDetail.html file was cached  in browser and dispite the fact data was always different the filters from template didn't even use.
I feel really noobish for this but it works now. Thank you for all your hints